# Why can a java nullable returned value be assigned to a Kotlin Non-Nullable variable?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm very surprise that the following code is compiled:

```
lateinit var progressBar: ProgressBar
```

and in `onCreate`:

```
progressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.pb_loader)
```

`findViewById` declared that it can return a `null`, so how doesn't the compiler enforce me to declare:

```
lateinit var progressBar: ProgressBar?
```

Can someone help me to understand when the compiler does enforce and when it doesn't?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`View.findViewById`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#findViewById(int)) is a Java function. The Kotlin compiler has no way of determining if it can return a nullable value or not since for Java only nullable types exist (even though they might never be null at runtime).

Annotations were introduced for the sake of documentation (and interoperability). [Some of them](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#nullability-annotations) can be used by the Kotlin compiler to determine the proper type.

But if the compiler cannot decide the type is regarded as [platform type](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#null-safety-and-platform-types), which means you as a developer have to decide at call-site if the value returned might be `null`.

Comment: Thanks, I understand. But when i'm using java method, and sending a non null argument to the method which expected no a null parameter, is it also compiled?

Comment: @DorVak The Java function's parameter must be annotated with `@NotNull` (org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull) then you get a compile time error in your Kotlin code. Of course there are other annoations as well, as described in the further reading linke of my answer :) But you need some kind of annoation, because there is no other way of expressing nullability in Java.

Comment: Ok, the thing that I see in the source code of *View.findViewById* that one line above the method  it is written *@Nullable*. Doesn't it mean something? or in other word: "worth something" :)

Comment: It depends on your build environment if it means something :)

Comment: Does it refer to method returned type? So it means that under some  definitions it can prevent me (compiler error) from assign the method returned value to a non null variable?

Comment: `findViewById` is marked `@Nullable` in the framework's Activity class, but not in the `androidx` subclass AppCompatActivity. So maybe this indirection causes Kotlin not to regard the method as annotated. And yes, it refers to the method return type.

Comment: @Tenfour04, I have also the same issue with *View* in a *Fragment*. After inflating the xml, i'm using the inflated view to get it's "children" via *finvViewById* (that as a nullable annotation), and still the compilder doesn't enforce that the variable i'm assigning to do  to be from nullable type. Sometimes it feels that Kotlin and Java doesn't go good together :) Isn't it?

Comment: You're just seeing Java's shortcoming leaking into Kotlin. `findViewById` I'm sure has caused many NPEs for people before Kotlin ever came along. I recommend looking into using view binding, which was created to avoid the problems with this method altogether.

Comment: @DorVak Can confirm that it even doesn't work with `View.findViewById`. Since this annoation is listed here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#nullability-annotations it might be a bug.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I guess you cannot always get around using findVIewById directly, for example in a `ViewHolder`

Answer (score 4):

From the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#null-safety-and-platform-types):

> Any reference in Java may be null, which makes Kotlin's requirements of strict null-safety impractical for objects coming from Java. Types of Java declarations are treated specially in Kotlin and called platform types. Null-checks are relaxed for such types, so that safety guarantees for them are the same as in Java

So yeah, this is expected behaviour. Kotlin doesn't check nullability if it comes from a Java API, unless you put [nullability annotations](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#nullability-annotations) on the method. `findViewById` unfortunately does not have such annotations.